# Styling the flutter arb files

Tags: flutter

```
     "verificationScreenInfoText": "If your sms code does not reach the {phoneNumber} in {timerText}, you can request a new sms code.",
  "@verificationScreenInfoText": {
    "placeholders": {
      "phoneNumber": {
        "type": "String",
        "example": "**********"
      },
      "timerText": {
        "type": "String",
        "example": "23:09"
      }
    }
  },
```

I have an arb file with this concept. I want to give text styling to,for example, {phoneNumber} bold. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the translation files, that is a single text object. You can not also should not give styling to the arb items anyway.

What you can do is use RichText and create different texts and for the prefix and suffix of the related parts of the related span.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        /// This can be AppLocalizations.current.numberPrefix
        text: 'If your sms code does not reach the ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: const <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: 'xxx-xxx-xx-xx', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          /// This can be AppLocalizations.current.numberSuffix
          TextSpan(text: ' in '),
          TextSpan(text: 'xx', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          /// This can be AppLocalizations.current.countDownSuffix
          TextSpan(text: ' seconds you can request a new sms code. '),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will look like the following:

[image: Screenshot of RichText]

Comment: Splitting the text won't solve my problem, i think. However, at the end of the day it looks i should go with this.

Comment: Why wouldn't it solve your problem? Styling a text in an arb file is not something you can or should do. Each TextSpan has its own attributes here and in Flutter there are two ways to do Rich Text. Either Flutter's RichText widget or the external libraries.

Comment: Let's say my text is not a just sentence but paragraph with lots of variables. With this approach, it's almost impossible to localize and style the text at the same time.

Comment: Yes for that purpose there are other attribute identifiers though. You can use RegEx matcing for special characters like <a> and create your text span accordingly. As I said, Rich Text is a quite a challenging topic and there is no straightforward answer.

Comment: Is there any example for your RegEx idea? I want to check that.

Comment: Give me a bit of time, I will prepare an example like above, later today.

Comment: Okey im waiting for you. Thanks a lot